Docker making endless copies of data
So I was trying to build a docker container, and I noticed that when running a WORKDIR instruction (which is supposed to change the working directory) it is taking ages (500+ seconds) and creating ~18GB of data (which is the size of all the data that is supposed to be copied in my image, and that was copied in beforehand.
On my docker install, I have changed the daemon's data root by putting "data_root": "path"  to another drive, because I lacked space, but since I did that it keeps copying loads of data like that, and I have no idea why. It not only does this for WORKDIR instructions, but for basically every instruction after I copy the 18 GB folder in...

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Ubuntu LTS 22.04
